# Add and Remove the Component onClick function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, jsx, react-functional-component

I started on React project. using functional components and hooks for development.

```
function comp1{
const addHandeler = () =>{
 //how to add component
}
return(<div> 
 <comp2/>
 // on click of add <comp2/> ...
<input type="button" id="add" value="Add" 
                            onClick={addHandeler} />
</div>)
}
```

I want to add multiple component comp2 on click of Add button inside div.

```
function comp2{

const deleteHandeler = () =>{
 // how to delete the component from comp1
}

return(
<div>
...
<input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete" 
     onClick={deleteHandeler}  />
</div>
)
}
```

similarly will have delete button, which will remove the comp2 from comp1 div.
Or let me know if there are any other best way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are adding and removing a list of components you need to have a unique identifier once create each one. here is a simplified vesion on how to approach with nanoId (you use it to create the id from new elements, not call it on map):

**Comp1**

```
import { nanoid } from 'nanoid'

function Comp1() {
  const [ids, setIds] = useState([])
  const addHandeler = () => {
    const newId = nanoid()
    setIds(ids => [...ids, newId])
  }

  const deleteHandeler = (removeId) => setIds(ids => ids.filter(id => id !== removeId))
  return(
    <div>
      { ids.map(id => <Comp2 key={id} deleteHandeler={() => deleteHandeler(id)} />) }

      <input type="button" id="add" value="Add" onClick={addHandeler} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Comp2**

```
function Comp2({ deleteHandeler }) {
  return (
  <div>
  <input type="button" id="delete" value="Delete" 
        onClick={deleteHandeler} />
  </div>
  )
}
```

[image: my-description]

Comment: TypeError: Object(...) is not a function for const newId = nanoid(), I installed naniod 2.1.11. I also changed const to let but no luck. I hope your solution will add and remove the component comp2 inside comp1.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/createremovecomponents-ziu6x?file=/src/App.js

Comment: fwiw, you could use others libs to generate unique id if you want to

Comment: i created a sandbox for you to check it out. it works as expected

Comment: Error in my editor,  "Could not find a declaration file for module 'nanoid'. '/projec/node_modules/nanoid/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type." It's look good in sandbox. but I am getting the same issue any idea.

Comment: I am using UUID and it's working, any idea how to include counter to display add 1, add 2, add 3. Thank you

Comment: you want to add multiple options, right? How about a select with dropdown quantity, and your addHandler checks that current state to define how many ids will be created?

Comment: Thanks but adding drop will change the UX. onClick of add we are adding component and want display component added 1 (coomp2-1) and if clicked again it will be comp2-2 and on delete count will be managed. Thank you